# macOS remap keys as modifiers

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, modifier-keys

## The situation

I use a keyboard layout called [3l (three layout)](https://github.com/sumnerevans/threelayout/) which is a layered keyboard layout. Here is the main layer (the behaviour when no modifier keys are pressed):

[image: normal 3l layout]

Now, when I am holding down the <kbd>'</kbd> on a normal keyboard (<kbd>sym</kbd> in 3l), I am in "symbols" mode and the rest of the keyboard behaves differently. Here's a picture of this mode:

[image: symbols layer of 3l]

Effectively, this symbols key is like a special <kbd>Shift</kbd> which allows me to access special characters.

Additionally, I have a numbers layer which has the same effect as the symbols layer and is activated by the <kbd>/</kbd> key, but has cursor and number-pad controls instead:

[image]

---

The person I forked my layout from already got the layout working in Linux and Windows (using AutoHotKey). I am trying to port it to macOS as well. So far I have created a `3l.keylayout` file ([see it here](https://github.com/sumnerevans/threelayout/blob/master/macos/3l.keylayout)) and have very basic functionality working.

### What's Working

1. The keys in normal mode work fine.
2. If I press the symbol modifier key, the first character I press is outputted as the correct symbol. For example, if I press the symbol key and then <kbd>O</kbd>, `/` is outputted.
3. The same goes for the cur/num key for the numberpad output.

### What's not Working

1. If I press and hold the symbol modifier key, and type multiple characters, only the first one actually outputs the symbol. (Same goes for the cur/num key as well.)
2. If I press and release one of the modifier keys and then press another key, the symbol/number is outputted. This should not be the case. When I release the modifier key, I want it to go back to normal mode (just like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key).
3. The cursor manipulation keys do not work reliably in all applications and they also have the issue of not allowing repeated keys when they do work.

## My Question

**Is there any way for me to get the functionality I described above in macOS (Sierra and later)?**

*Note*: I have also tried to remap <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> to Right Option and Right Control using Karabiner Elements and then attempted to create a new `keymap` in `3l.keylayout` that is activated by those keys. This did not work, however. It screwed everything up and I got into a perpetual control/option key situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue using [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)' complex modifications.

Here is my complete [`karabiner.json`](https://github.com/sumnerevans/threelayout/blob/master/macosx/karabiner.json) file.

Under `profiles -> rules -> manipulators`, I added two manipulators. One for `sym` and one for `cur`.

I copied the `sym` manipulator below:

```
{
    "conditions": [

            "name": "sym",
            "type": "variable_if",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "cur",
            "type": "variable_if",
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "key_code": "quote",
        "modifiers": {
            "optional": [
                "any"
            ]
        }
    },
    "to": [
        {
            "set_variable": {
                "name": "sym",
                "value": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "to_after_key_up": [
        {
            "set_variable": {
                "name": "sym",
                "value": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "basic"
}
```

Then I went through every key setting, i.e. when the key is pressed with no modifier, the `sym` modifier, and the `cur` modifier.

This works flawlessly.